# Encoding tuples within a list

Tags: python, list, nlp, tuples, text-mining

I have a list of tuples and I want to encode them, can someone tell me on how to do the same.
For example in the case below I want to assign a value to ('Hi', 'VB'), ie I want to assign a value (integer) to every tuple in the below list (Maybe it's called vectorizing as well) .

```
[('Hi', 'VB'),
 ('remind', 'VB'),
 ('me', 'PRP'),
 ('regarding', 'IN'),
 ('ice', 'JJ'),
 ('cream,', 'NN'),
 ('in', 'VBG'),
 ('around', 'RB'),
 ('11am', 'CD')]
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking *"I want to assign a value (integer) "*. Sample output will be helpful. Also, what have you tried to achieve this?

Comment: `{key: value for value, key in enumerate(values)}` where `values` is your original list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) :

```
tuples = [('Hi', 'VB'),
 ('remind', 'VB'),
 ('me', 'PRP'),
 ('regarding', 'IN'),
 ('ice', 'JJ'),
 ('cream,', 'NN'),
 ('in', 'VBG'),
 ('around', 'RB'),
 ('11am', 'CD')]

my_dict = {}
for i, tuple in enumerate(tuples):
  my_dict[tuple] = i

print my_dict
# {('in', 'VBG'): 6, ('regarding', 'IN'): 3, ('me', 'PRP'): 2, ('cream,', 'NN'): 5, ('11am', 'CD'): 8, ('remind', 'VB'): 1, ('Hi', 'VB'): 0, ('around', 'RB'): 7, ('ice', 'JJ'): 4}
print my_dict[('me', 'PRP')]
#=> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

`tuples` in python are *hashable*. So you can use them as a key in python dictionary. So it is the simple case of creating a `dict` out of the list of tuples.

```
values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
tuples = [('Hi', 'VB'),
 ('remind', 'VB'),
 ('me', 'PRP'),
 ('regarding', 'IN'),
 ('ice', 'JJ'),
 ('cream,', 'NN'),
 ('in', 'VBG'),
 ('around', 'RB'),
 ('11am', 'CD')]

res_dict = dict(zip(tuples, values))
```

Print out `res_dict` -

```
{('remind', 'VB'): 2, ('me', 'PRP'): 3, ('11am', 'CD'): 9, ('in', 'VBG'): 7, ('ice', 'JJ'): 5, ('cream,', 'NN'): 6, ('Hi', 'VB'): 1, ('around', 'RB'): 8, ('regarding', 'IN'): 4}
```